# Filling company tab with dynamic value

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to fill a company tab with the name of a company that I send along with the request. However, whenever I do so, the company name that appears in the company tab is the company name attached to my Developer Account, not the one I specify in the 'value' field.

Here's my envelope definition:

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
    <emailSubject>COMPANY NAME Has Sent A Document for You to Sign</emailSubject>
    <status>sent</status>
    <documents>
        <document>
            <documentId>1</documentId>
            <name>file.rtf</name>
        </document>
    </documents>

    <recipients>
        <signers>
            <signer>
                <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                <email>buyer@site.com</email>
                <name>Bobby Buyer</name>
                <routingOrder>1</routingOrder>
                <tabs>
                    <signHereTabs>
                        <signHere>
                            <anchorString>//bs01_01//</anchorString>
                            <anchorXOffset>1.5</anchorXOffset>
                            <anchorYOffset>0.0</anchorYOffset>
                            <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>true</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
                            <anchorUnits>inches</anchorUnits>
                            <documentID>1</documentID>
                            <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
                            <recipientID>1</recipientID>
                            <optional>false</optional>
                        </signHere>
                    </signHereTabs>

            <signer>
                <recipientId>2</recipientId>
                <email>seller@sitea.com</email>
                <name>Sally Seller</name>
                <routingOrder>2</routingOrder>
                <tabs>
                    <signHereTabs>
                        <signHere>
                            <anchorString>//ss01_01//</anchorString>
                            <anchorXOffset>1.5</anchorXOffset>
                            <anchorYOffset>0.0</anchorYOffset>
                            <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>true</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
                            <anchorUnits>inches</anchorUnits>
                            <documentID>1</documentID>
                            <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
                            <recipientID>2</recipientID>
                            <optional>false</optional>
                        </signHere>
                    </signHereTabs>

                    <companyTabs>
                        <company>
                            <anchorString>//sco01_01//</anchorString>
                            <anchorXOffset>0.0</anchorXOffset>
                            <anchorYOffset>0.0</anchorYOffset>
                            <anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>true</anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent>
                            <anchorUnits>inches</anchorUnits>
                            <documentID>1</documentID>
                            <pageNumber>1</pageNumber>
                            <recipientID>2</recipientID>
                            <optional>false</optional>
                            <concealValueOnDocument>false</concealValueOnDocument>
                            <tabLabel>compName</tabLabel>
                            <value>COMPANY NAME</value>
                            <locked>false</locked>
                        </company>

                </tabs>
            </signer>
        </signers>
    </recipients>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

Additionally, I'd like for *every* recipient to be able to see the company name, since that's what I assume the `<concealValueOnDocument>` tag does. However, it does not do that, so it must not do what I think it should be doing.

Comment: Did adding the closing tab work??

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing the closing `</companyTabs>` node.  Right now you have:

```
<companyTabs>
    <company>
        <anchorString>//sco01_01//</anchorString>
        ...
    </company>
```

Try changing to:

```
<companyTabs>
    <company>
        <anchorString>//sco01_01//</anchorString>
        ...
    </company>      
</companyTabs>
```

Comment: Did this work for you?  If so can you accept as answer and upvote?